# Why is my laptop getting high CPU load, when playing videos or discord screen sharing?

Tags: cpu

It doesn't happen always, when playing 1080p videos from [FreeTube](https://freetubeapp.io/). Sometimes, it even happens when watching 240p videos (but it takes more time to happen).

Although, it always happens when watching to high quality Discord screen sharing.

I'm not necessarily looking for a solution, because there might be none. I need to know how I can debug this.

**what I have already**

- switching from video window to terminal (`alt + tab`), makes CPU load drop about 50%;
- when I use `htop` command, it shows that the villain is Firefox, sometimes (even though Firefox is just there, with only `about:blank` opened);
- I've just installed `psensor` and set an alarm, so I know if this is related to CPU temperature. I'll let you know about possible outcomes.

**what do I do to investigate this further, guys?** I never faced this problem on Windows, using this laptop. Being able to share my screen on Discord is very important!

**more informations**

I've got 4GB RAM.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10
Release:    20.10
Codename:   groovy
```

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          2
On-line CPU(s) list:             0,1
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              2
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           37
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 560  @ 2.67GHz
Stepping:                        5
CPU MHz:                         2659.929
BogoMIPS:                        5319.85
Virtualization:                  VT-x
L1d cache:                       64 KiB
L1i cache:                       64 KiB
L2 cache:                        512 KiB
L3 cache:                        3 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0,1
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled
```

`lspci | grep VGA`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
```

#### Question Updates

I ran this command, as requested: `$ sudo apt install -y vainfo`

```
libva info: VA-API version 1.8.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_8
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 1
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_6
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.8 (libva 2.8.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile - 2.4.0
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
```

Comment: Please add more information like which OS you use, system details like graphics, ram, cpu and which graphics driver.

Comment: @pLumo Done! Let me know if it's enough. I used all commands I know.

Answer (score 0):

You should extend your question and provide the graphics card you use.

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

It is possible that you don't have proper graphics drivers installed, therefore [hardware video acceleration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Hardware_video_acceleration) doesn't work and your CPU has to do all this job itself.

CPU/GPU load also depends on which video codecs are used. I see that Discord [supports](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-enable-hardware-acceleration-in-Discord) hardware acceleration and uses [H.264](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding) video codec.

Also, make sure your power setting daemon (if you have one) does not limit your GPU/CPU power.

Comment: Updated body with required information. Also: how do I check if I have a power setting daemon?

Comment: For the graphics card, I think Ubuntu uses some kind of driver manager. Could you take a look inside and try to find something related to Intel graphics?

Comment: Could you install `libva-utils` and provide output of `vainfo` command?

Comment: I used `$ sudo apt install -y vainfo`, instead.

Comment: Question body updated with requested information.